# Python pandas dataframe.value returns a ndarray with strange properties, that can be plotted but break lmfit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, lmfit

I am working on an assignment that requires me to fit different kinetic models to some concentration versus time data. In order to acomplish this I performed the following steps:

1.Imported a spreadsheet into a python Jupyter notebook with pandas.read_excel and then removed all the columns after row 20

```
data = pd.read_excel("assignment1.xlsx")[:21]
```

2.plotted some of the data

```
X = data["X"].values
t = np.linspace(0,20,len(X))
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,X)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("Conversion(x)")
```

3.attempted to fit a model to the data

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Model, Parameter

X2 = data["X"].values
t2 = np.linspace(0,20.1,len(X))
y2 = (data["A"].values+data["B"].values)*X
y3 = []
t3 = []


for y in y2: #these are used a little later 
    y3.append(y)
for t in t2:
    t3.append(t)


def test2(t,k):
    return t*k 

aModel = Model(test2)

p = aModel.make_params()
p["k"] = Parameter(name="k",value=3,min=0)



result = aModel.fit(np.array(y2),params=p,t=np.array(t2)) #source of error
```

but I got the following error...

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

yet the following code along with the previous block minus the result line does not give me an error

```
result = aModel.fit(np.array(y3),params=p,t=np.array(t3)) #y3, t3 replaces t2, y2
```

Obviously there is something wrong with df.values in that it returns some odd numpy array that is ok for plotting but not ok for fitting. Does anyone have an idea about what the difference is between these two arrays or how I could go about fixing the error in a more graceful way?

**EDIT:** 
Here is some additional information that some of the commenters have asked for: 
Here are the t2, y2 shape and type 
code:

```
print("t2 shape: ", t2.shape, "t2 type: ", type(t2))
print("y2 shape: ", y2.shape, "y2 type: ", type(y2))
```

output:

```
t2 shape:  (21,) t2 type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
y2 shape:  (21,) y2 type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-312-0681483eeeeb> in <module>()
     28 
     29 
---> 30 result = aModel.fit(np.array(y2),params=p,t=np.array(t2))
     31 
     32 print(test2([0,3,0,3,0],1))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in fit(self, data, params, weights, method, iter_cb, scale_covar, verbose, fit_kws, nan_policy, **kwargs)
    871                              scale_covar=scale_covar, fcn_kws=kwargs,
    872                              nan_policy=self.nan_policy, **fit_kws)
--> 873         output.fit(data=data, weights=weights)
    874         output.components = self.components
    875         return output

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py in fit(self, data, params, weights, method, nan_policy, **kwargs)
   1215         self.userkws.update(kwargs)
   1216         self.init_fit = self.model.eval(params=self.params, **self.userkws)
-> 1217         _ret = self.minimize(method=self.method)
   1218 
   1219         for attr in dir(_ret):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py in minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   1809                         val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   1810                     kwargs['method'] = val
-> 1811         return function(**kwargs)
   1812 
   1813 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py in leastsq(self, params, **kws)
   1362 
   1363         try:
-> 1364             lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
   1365             _best, _cov, infodict, errmsg, ier = lsout
   1366             result.residual = infodict['fvec']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    392         with _MINPACK_LOCK:
    393             retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 394                                      gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    395     else:
    396         if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, not just the error

Comment: check the shape and dtype

Comment: I edited the original post to include the traceback as well as the shape and type of t2 and y2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not fully answer the question, but might point you in the right direction and is too long for a comment anyway.

Without knowing the details of your `xlsx` file, it looks like your code should work.  I think the most likely clue from the traceback is the message "... is not a proper array of floats".  You are coercing the data and `x` array to be numpy arrays, but they may not be Float64 (double precision) arrays.

So check the datatype as well as the shape and type of the ndarrays:

```
print("t2 shape: ", t2.shape, "t2 type: ", type(t2), "t2 dtype: ", t2.dtype)
```

For the fit to work, this must be `dtype('float64')`.

The arrays might be integer array if the values in the spreadsheet are all integers.  In that case, just do

```
t2 = np.array(t2, dtype='float64')
```

or

```
t2 = np.asfarray(t2)
```

and so on to force the arrays to be Float64.

Or, it might also be that the arrays are "object arrays" if the Series from the spreadsheet mixes numerical and non-numerical data.  In that case, you'll have to remove the non-numerical rows, and/or force the dtype to Float64.

Comment: I put in the print statement that you recomended and got the following output. <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
t2 shape:  (21,) t2 type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> t2 dtype:  float64 . I think you are right about the problem being related to the dtype, though. If you notice in my code I don't get an error when I fill up a list with the data and use that for the fitting. Currently i am using that work around. I will try the t2 = np.array(t2, dtype='foat64') line and see if that works.